# self join dataframe in r

Tags: sql, r, join, dataframe

I have a table consisting of publication_id and the author names

[image]

I want to find all the coauthors per each author i.e., who all worked together.

I am able to get all the publications each author obtained like this

```
   pubsperauthor <- sample_pubs_small %>% 
       group_by(cname) %>% 
       summarise(pubs = toString(sort(unique(publication_id))))
```

[image]

Now I want to get the names of all coauthors for that pub. Any suggestions?

Here is the code for the data

```
> dput(pubsperauthor)
structure(list(cname = c("AMEY S BAILEY", "JACK  SMITH", "JACK A SMITH", 
"JACK B SMITH", "JAMES  ANDERSON", "JAMES M ANDERSON", "RONALD  VALE", 
"RONALD A VALE", "RONALD DAVID VALE"), pubs = c("6", "6", "4", 
"5", "1, 2", "4, 5, 6", "3", "0", "1, 2")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("cname", 
"pubs"))
> dput(sample_pubs_small)
structure(list(publication_id = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), cname = c("RONALD A VALE", "JAMES  ANDERSON", 
"RONALD DAVID VALE", "JAMES  ANDERSON", "RONALD DAVID VALE", 
"RONALD  VALE", "JAMES M ANDERSON", "JACK A SMITH", "JAMES M ANDERSON", 
"JACK B SMITH", "JAMES M ANDERSON", "AMEY S BAILEY", "JACK  SMITH"
)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("publication_id", "cname"))
```

Edit

Here is sample output

```
1     AMEY S BAILEY                          JACK  SMITH, JAMES M ANDERSON
2       JACK  SMITH                        AMEY S BAILEY, JAMES M ANDERSON
3      JACK A SMITH                                       JAMES M ANDERSON
4      JACK B SMITH                                       JAMES M ANDERSON
5   JAMES  ANDERSON                                      RONALD DAVID VALE
6  JAMES M ANDERSON AMEY S BAILEY, JACK  SMITH, JACK A SMITH, JACK B SMITH
7 RONALD DAVID VALE                                        JAMES  ANDERSON
8     RONALD A VALE
9       RONALD VALE
```

Comment: You want all authors name for each publication id?

Comment: I want co author names for each author

Comment: Should I assume that the first appearance of the `cname` is the author and the next ones are the co author? For example: id = 4; Author: JAMES M ANDERSON; co-author: JACK A SMITH

Comment: I just used the term co-author to exclude the correct author for which we want to find all other authors they worked with. So James M Anderson will have the following co-authors - Jack A Smith, Jack B Smith, Amey S Bailey, Jack Smith

Comment: Please post desired data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to get list of coauthors for each author.  Please note that it drops authors with no coauthors.  So you may wish to do another join with a complete list of authors depending on your desired final data structure.

```
coauthor <- sample_pubs_small %>% 
  left_join(sample_pubs_small, by = "publication_id") %>% 
  subset(cname.x != cname.y) %>% 
  group_by(cname.x) %>% 
  summarise(Coauthors = toString(sort(unique(cname.y))))
```

Comment: to obtain a list of the coauthors instead of strings - we can say =  `summarise(Coauthors = list(sort(unique(cname.y))))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to keep authors with no co-autors with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
sample_pubs_small%>%
left_join(sample_pubs_small, by="publication_id") %>%
mutate(cname.y=ifelse(cname.x==cname.y,NA,cname.y)) %>%
group_by(cname.x)%>%
summarise(coauthors = toString(sort(unique(cname.y))))

            cname.x                                              coauthors
              <chr>                                                  <chr>
1     AMEY S BAILEY                          JACK  SMITH, JAMES M ANDERSON
2       JACK  SMITH                        AMEY S BAILEY, JAMES M ANDERSON
3      JACK A SMITH                                       JAMES M ANDERSON
4      JACK B SMITH                                       JAMES M ANDERSON
5   JAMES  ANDERSON                                      RONALD DAVID VALE
6  JAMES M ANDERSON AMEY S BAILEY, JACK  SMITH, JACK A SMITH, JACK B SMITH
7      RONALD  VALE                                                       
8     RONALD A VALE                                                       
9 RONALD DAVID VALE                                        JAMES  ANDERSON
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ian Wesley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7384676/ian-wesley) already gave the answer but I'll add something useful.

You can use `aggregate` to get the `pubsperauthor`:

```
pubsperauthor <- aggregate(publication_id ~ cname, sample_pubs_small, c)
```

And you can do the same thing to get `authorsperpub`, which will give all authors for each publication (which is in some way the coauthors)

```
authorsperpub <- aggregate(cname ~ publication_id, sample_pubs_small, c)
```